# How to solve variables of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of linear equations.

\begin{aligned}
2x+ky+2z &=0 \\
x-y+z    &=1 \\
y-z      &=k
\end{aligned}

Using the augmented matrix, I get

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &k &2 &0 \\
1 &-1& 1& 1 \\
0 &1& -1 &k 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Putting it into row echelon form, I get

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & k/2& 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1  & -1 & k\\
0 & 0  &  1 & -\dfrac{(k²+2· k+2}{k+2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is the reduced echelon form I get. Yes I could get others. Yes I could get much simpler ones. But THIS is the one I am working with .

I get the solution of $z=-\dfrac{(k²+2· k+2)}{k+2}$.

I am not sure how to expand that negative sign in front of the brackets, this is the result from my calculator. Any help would be great ;))

I then find y to be equal to $y=k+z$. I get $y=\dfrac{4k+4}{k+2}$.

Then $x$ would be equal to $k+1$, but what I get is $x=-k-1$.

So practically I am having some issues computing the solutions of this problem. I know the system is consistent when $k$ is NOT equal to $-2$, if it might be of use. I am just curious to know if $x=k+1$ is the real answer, and if so, how to get there with algebra (which I'm pretty bad at ). Moreover, any help on trying to see if my $y$ is correct would be great.

Edit: i checked the answers, on the calculator, i get x=k+1

z=-2/(k+2)

and y=-(k²+2· k+2)/k+2

I imagine my problem is EXACTLY this x solution :I don't know how to expand it properly . I don't get what is multiplied, if 2 · (k+2) or (2· k)+2

Answer (score 0):

Your $z$ is correct, but not your $y$: from $y=k+z$, you obtain
$$y=k-\dfrac{k²+2k+2}{k+2}=\dfrac{k(k+2)-(k²+2k+2)}{k+2}=-\dfrac{2}{k+2}$$
and the second equation yields
$$x=1+(y-z)=1+k\qquad\text{by the third equation}.$$

Comment: how would the −(k²+2k+2) expand? e.g −k²-2k-2)?

Comment: So would z= −k²-2k-2 / (k+2) ?

Comment: Why, yes. The $-$ goes to the numerator or to the denominator, as you wish.

Comment: Well, if it originally stands on the numerator, shouldn't i keep it on the numerator...

Comment: I just wanted to know that with a negative sign in front of brackets, its as if there were a negative one, so it becomes −k²-2k-2

Comment: Yes, it's distributive. As to your other question, it's a basic rule that $$-\frac ab=\frac{-a}b=\frac a{-b}.$$

Comment: Can you please expand a bit how you got 1+k? Becuase i thought of using the first equation , which would be x + y (k/2) + z = 0

Comment: I was thinking of using the first equation : x+y(k/2)+z=0 and then find x. But that is really a LOT of work

Comment: Please tell me how you got x !!

Comment: I wrote it: the shortest way starts from the second equation (rewritten as $x=1+y-z$) and took into account the third equation: $y-z=k$.

Comment: as i see you have a really good reputation , I was willing to ask you if maybe you knew this question • An integrable function on an interval cannot have jumps. I think it is true? am i correct? I know a differentiable function cannot have jumps. I am asking you because i can't post any more questions

Comment: That's not true: [step functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function) are integrable, yet usually have jumps. If by ‘integrable’, you only mean a function $f$ for which  there exists a differentiable function $F$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$, it's more complex as such functions satisty the *Intermediate Value Theorem* even though they need not be continuous

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine the row reduction:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &k &2 &0 \\
1 &-1& 1& 1 \\
0 &1& -1 &k 
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &k/2 &1 &0 \\
1 &-1& 1& 1 \\
0 &1& -1 &k 
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_1\gets\tfrac{1}{2}R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &k/2 &1 &0 \\
0 &-1-k/2& 0& 1 \\
0 &1& -1 &k 
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\gets R_2-R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &k/2 &1 &0 \\
0 &1& 0& -2/(k+2) \\
0 &1& -1 &k 
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\gets -\tfrac{2}{k+2}R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &k/2 &1 &0 \\
0 &1& 0& -\tfrac{2}{k+2} \\
0 &0& -1 &\tfrac{k^2+2k+2}{k+2}
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets R_3-R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &k/2 &1 &0 \\
0 &1& 0& -\tfrac{2}{k+2} \\
0 &0& 1 &-\tfrac{k^2+2k+2}{k+2}
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets -R_3
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &k/2 &0 & \tfrac{k^2+2k+2}{k+2} \\
0 &1& 0& -\tfrac{2}{k+2} \\
0 &0& 1 &-\tfrac{k^2+2k+2}{k+2}
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_1\gets R_1-R_3
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &0 & k+1 \\
0 &1& 0& -\tfrac{2}{k+2} \\
0 &0& 1 &-\tfrac{k^2+2k+2}{k+2}
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_1\gets R_1-\tfrac{k}{2}R_2
\end{align}

This assuming $k\ne-2$. When $k=-2$ the second step above yields
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
and the row reduction goes on like
\begin{align}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\leftrightarrow R_2
\end{align}
so the system has no solution.

Comment: How would you get x=k+1 from my row echelon form ?

Comment: @MichaelMorello Go on to the reduced row echelon form.